# simple modal resizing and centering?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am using simplemodal to bring up a modal with some content in it.

Inside that content i am making a ajax call to some other content which is a different size from the original content (quite a bit smaller)

what i'm doing that is kind of working is using jQuery to change the size of the modal container.

in the oncomplete section of my ajax call i use the following jquery

```
jQuery("#simplemodal-container").animate({ height: 550 }, 500);
jQuery("#simplemodal-container").animate({ width: 493}, 500);'
```

there is two problems with this.

in different browsers the width is slightly different so the modal content doesn't look quite right

and the modal maintains it's original position. it doesn't recenter itself in the browser window.

does anyone know how to resize simplemodal based on new content inside of a open modal?

thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

My SimpleModal Auto Width/Height and centered modal code:

```
$('#sampleDiv').modal({
onShow: function (dialog) {
            var h = $(window).height();
            var w = $(window).width();
            dialog.container.css('height', 'auto');
            dialog.container.css('width', 'auto');
            var h2 = dialog.container.height();
            var w2 = dialog.container.width();  
            var top = (h/2)-(h2/2)-h2;  
            var left = (w/2)-(w2/2)-w2;                                                         
            dialog.container.css('left', left+'px');
            dialog.container.css('top', top+'px');
    }
});
```

Working IE,FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an error. It should be: 
`var top = (h/2)-(h2/2);
var left = (w/2)-(w2/2);`

Answer (score 0):

An example like the following should work for you:

```
$('#modalContentTest').modal({onShow: function (dialog) {
    var sm = this;
    dialog.container.animate({height: 550, width: 493}, 500, function () {
        sm.setPosition();   
    });
}});
```

Comment: i don't think i explained myself properly.

i want to have modal 1 open,

then inside modal 1 a ajax call replaces content inside the div.

the content from the ajax call is smaller than the original content to i need to resize the modal and recenter it.

the code in the example works perfect if the modal is not already open but what i'm trying to do is recenter a modal when the modal is already open. the only way i can figure to do it is to close and open another modal right away. 

is there any way to do this without closing the original modal?

Comment: I think I understood your original question, you'd just need to modify the code I provided to fit your needs.

You would need to add the ajax call into the onShow callback and then move the dialog.container.animate section of code inside the ajax success callback. The dimensions you would get from data coming back.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far

function modalThree($type) {
        var $type;

```
    jQuery("#simplemodal-container").animate({ width: 250 }, 0);
    jQuery("#simplemodal-container").animate({"left": "+=200px"}, "fast");
    jQuery("#simplemodal-container").animate({"top": "-=50px"}, "fast");


    jQuery('#simplemodal-container').css({
    position:'absolute',
    left: (jQuery(window).width() - jQuery('#simplemodal-container').outerWidth())/2,
    top: (jQuery(window).height() - jQuery('#simplemodal-container').outerHeight())/2
    });


    jQuery("#dialog").load("/default/modalTwo", function()
    {
      jQuery("#dialog").modal({
      overlay:80,
      autoResize:true,
      overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#000"}
      });
    });
}
```

my site is pretty much a fixed width and i know the size of the content from the ajax call.

i resize it using the following

jQuery("#simplemodal-container").animate({ width: 250 }, 0);
jQuery("#simplemodal-container").animate({"left": "+=200px"}, "fast");
jQuery("#simplemodal-container").animate({"top": "-=50px"}, "fast");

it kind of works but i'd like to calculate how much left and top is has to go based on the window size.

it works but i'm not sure if it is the solution.